# MYSQL/PHP selecting

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables :

- `newpw_ask`

  ```
  email
  code
  ```
- `users`

  ```
  id
  username
  password
  email
  sid
  newpw_code
  ```

I have this PHP code:

```
$code = $_POST['code2'];
$email = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM pw_ask WHERE code='$code'");

if ($pass == $pass2) {
    if ($email) {
        $pass3 = md5($pass);

        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET password='$pass3' WHERE email='$email'");
        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET newpw_code='' WHERE email='$email'");
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM pw_ask WHERE code='$code'");

        header("Location: index.php?ret=pw");
    } else {
        echo 'Wrong code';
    }
}
```

Only this query got executed:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM pw_ask WHERE code='$code'");
```

Also when I enter the right code, it says “Wrong code”.

Comment: Please read this guide on hashing passwords. md5 is not nearly good enough. http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Comment: Good Lord, don't use this. `$this="Everything";` - Whoever contributes to answering this, shouldn't; ***period.*** And if they do, give a reason why. I never contribute to question that use passwords stored in plain text or `md5`.

Comment: Just a comment: use mysqli_* instead of mysql_*

Comment: You're not [properly escaping values](http://bobby-tables.com/php), creating several severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). You're also using the deprecated `mysql_query` which should not be used in new applications because it's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) shows how to avoid making these sorts of mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

You need to select the email correctly :

```
$sql    = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM pw_ask WHERE code='$code'");
$row    = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$email  = $row['email'];
```

btw you can also update multiple fields in 1 query :

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET password='$pass3' , newpw_code='' where email='$email'");
```

Comment: Was going to put that but trying to remember the syntax as I use PDO

Comment: print email to see what it contains , you "$codes" are unique ?

Comment: @user3287874 what was the problem ?

Comment: Actually i don't know,i just re-pasted your code to try something and it's worked,thanks.

Comment: Ah i know why,i modified $row string to $row2 and i didn't modified $row['email'].